# What is the appropriate normalization for finding correlations between Poisson distributions?

Tags: pca, poisson-distribution, covariance, poisson-regression, poisson-process

I am interested in using this algorithm, [glm-pca](https://github.com/willtownes/glmpca-py), to find a lower dimensional embedding in time series data, specifically neuronal spiking data, which is Poisson distributed. I have looked at some posts regarding finding the covariance of two Poisson distributions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3707140/joint-distribution-and-covariance-of-poisson-process-and-waiting-time and I am just curious what if any normalization should be applied to my data.  It will be a very sparse time series of counts basically.  I may decrease the window size to reduce the size of the matrix and speed up computation.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "normalization" and how it could even affect estimations of covariance?